# Systematic way of of reducing (by grouping) number of parameters of a function

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations

Consider the function $f(x,y) = (x + y)^2 + \log(x+y)$. Obviously this function does not depend on $x$ and $y$ seperately, instead, it depends on $z=x+y$. So, $f(z) = z^2 + \log(z)$.

So what if we have a complicated function of several variables and we want to reduce the number of variables by finding such $z$ functions? Is there any systematic way of doing this?

I tried a bit and it seems like I will end up some linear partial differential equation describing $z$.

For this example,
$$f_x = f_z z_x$$
$$f_y = f_zz_y$$

Thus we have

$$f_xz_y - f_yz_x = 0$$

We know $f(x,y)$ and so this is just a partial differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

For fixed $y\;$ $f(\cdot,y)$ is a function of $x$ (and similarly for $x$), so $f$ does depend on $x$ and $y$ separately. I believe what you would like to say is that $f$ somehow incorporates two of its variables by first adding them, which you can formalize as follows: Supposing $\operatorname{dom}(f)=\Bbb{R}^2$, let $\operatorname{add}:\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}, (x,y)\mapsto x+y$ and $g:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}, z\mapsto z^2+\log(z)$. Then $f\equiv g\circ\operatorname{add}$. This can be considered to be somewhat systematic, though probably the more accurate word is categorical.